# How do I create a serial number in SQL for INSERT?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I'm saving data to a table, but I also need a column with a serial number. How do I do that? (I'm doing this in C#, perhaps it matters.)

This must be pretty simple, but googling hasn't been successful.

EDIT: I don't want to just save an integer. I want to give SQL a command to create it when saving, because if I create an integer and save it between creating it and saving it – another query might try to save the same number at the same time, and I'll get two entries with the same number.)

Comment: Have you heard about Auto_increment till now

Comment: Use identity column with AutoIncerement set to 1.:)

Comment: what do you mean saying "serial number" ? Identity field?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`IDENTITY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property?view=sql-server-2017):

```
CREATE TABLE YourTable
(
    ID INT IDENTITY
)
```

Each time you insert a new record SQL Server will take care of incrementing this value for you (no two records will have the same number, it is unique).

Comment: @ispiro - no serial number is required, the identity column will take care of this for you.  It is not a hidden field, rather the key to identify a row. Try it out and insert a few records and select from the table, you will see.

Answer (score 1):

The best approach is not programmatic, but let your database automatically create an incrementing field. In SQL Server this is called an [identity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933196%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) column.

In your insert statement, you simply skip over that column as if it doesn't exist but SQL Server will automatically increment and populate it for you.

Answer (score 1):

Uniqueidentifier solves the problem, but it isn't scalable, the column is no suitable to create a Clustered index, because the resulting index is very large and it's values isn't allways increasing (restriction over well defined clustered index).

Keyword IDENTITY is much adequate, you can choose among the integer datatypes acordingly your needs (smallint, int, bigint...) you can get safely the last value asigned through the function scope_identity()

Answer (score 0):

Use `IDENTITY` that is available in sql. Below is example

```
CREATE TABLE Persons
(
P_Id int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
FirstName varchar(255),
Address varchar(255),
City varchar(255)
)
```

### [Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp)

Answer (score 0):

define serial number as primary key NOT NULL and Auto Increment. Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

What do you think about using a GUID (aka [UNIQUEIDENTIFIER](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187942%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) datatype in SQL Server)?

```
DECLARE @myid uniqueidentifier = NEWID();
SELECT @myid
```